# Script to cycle through folders and copy a specific file

Tags: windows-7, script

I need a script to cycle through folder and copy the folder name and save it in 'temp'. Then within that folder copy a specific file and paste it into another folder with the name 'temp.dat'

For example, take 
“drivers.dat” folder name, extract “drivers”
Then copy ‘drivers.dat’\’dat’ file, move and rename to new_dat\drivers.dat

Thanks for the help.

---

Lets say the path is network path L:\Personal Folders. Over here
1)  Create a “new_dat” folder
2)  Cycle through the folders in the directory and:
a.  Take the folder name, extract the folder name without the .dat extention, save the name
b.   In that folder copy and rename the dat file to name_dat.dat
c.  Copy the new dat file to the “new_dat” folder.
3)  Repeat for every folder.dat

For example, take 
“2.5V drivers.dat” folder name, extract “2.5V drivers”
Then copy ‘2.5V drivers.dat’\’dat’ file, move and rename to new_dat\2.5 V drivers.dat

We’ll end up with a new_dat folder containing all the “dat” files but renamed as “folder name.dat".

Comment: be a little more clear, I have no clue what you are wanting to do

Comment: show me the folder structure and I will write a script

Comment: Hi David! Please **register your account** here so you can edit your posts and add comments. It seems you lost your cookie, which is why I manually had to add your answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was updated. I dont think your powershell script does what I wanted it to do. Is my explanation still confusing.

Comment: Basically I have a folder "Personal Folder".....within this folder I have 400 folders where all are named as "some_name.dat" Within these "some_name.dat" folders there are multiple files but there is 1 file in all the 400 folders that I am interested in extracting. The name of that file is 'dat'. What I am interested in doing is this......I made a new folder inside "Personal Folder" named "New"....I want to extract the 'dat' file from all those 400 folders and place it under "New"

Comment: but the only way I can distinduish between these 400 'dat' files is by naming them differently.....so I was thinking of naming them by their respective folder names...from which they were extracted......for example, if 'dat' file was extracted from "Test.dat" then we will save the dat file as Test.dat under "New". Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: updated to do what you want. ive also tested it. Please mark as answer when you get a chance, thanks!

Comment: Hi Taylor, Thanks for your reply. I tried running the script and this is the message I get: Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Directory'.
At C:\Users\test\Desktop\Move.ps1:13 char:36
+ $Folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory <<<<  | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "new_mbx"}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: Also, what happened was all of my 400 directories were just cut and paste under "New" folder as follows: New\_dat.dat\all 400 folders. There are multiple files under all those 400 folders, I only want to move the file named 'dat' That file has no extension just the name 'dat'

Answer (score 0):

Heres one written in PowerShell 3.

```
#Set Location to Folder
Set-Location -Path "C:\Personal Folders"

#Check If The Folder "new_dat" exists, if it doesnt, create it
if(!(Test-Path -Path "new_dat"))
{
    New-Item -Name "new_dat" -ItemType Directory
}

#Get All The Folders Except "new_dat"
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "new_dat"}

#This Is Where The Magic Happens
foreach($Folder in $Folders)
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder.FullName -Filter *.dat | Move-Item -Destination  (Join-Path -ChildPath ([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($Folder.Name) + "_dat.dat") -Path "C:\Personal Folders\new_dat" )
}
```

- Install PowerShell 3
- Put that into a text file and call it Move.ps1
- Set up a scheduled task to make it run every X hours or whatever

Comment: Good plan.  My contribution is to say make the program in Task Scheduler PowerShell and the argument -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "PathTo\..\Move.ps1"

Comment: Good catch, I always seem to take execution policies for granted.